# Is it possible to merge these non clustered indexes to reduce space?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

Still learning about indexes in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have three indexes on one table and there's about 10 million rows of data i want to know if i can merge the indexes to reduce space as they take a few gigs each.

Queries:

```
Select * 
From dbo.Table1
Where ColumnA in ('1')

Select * 
From dbo.Table1
Where ColumnA in ('1')
  And ColumnB in ('2')

Select * 
From dbo.Table1
Where ColumnA in ('1')
  And ColumnB in ('2')
  And ColumnC in ('3')
```

Indexes:

```
Create Nonclustered Index [SomeIndex1] 
on dbo.Table1 (ColumnA Asc)
Include(ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD)

Create Nonclustered Index [SomeIndex2] 
on dbo.Table1(ColumnA Asc, ColumnB Asc)
Include (ColumnC, ColumnD)

Create Nonclustered Index [SomeIndex3] 
on dbo.Table1(ColumnA Asc, ColumnB Asc, ColumnC Asc)
Include (ColumnD)
```

Comment: If your *only* goal is to reduce space usage, just delete all of the indexes.

Comment: `SomeIndex3` should in fact be able to handle all three sample queries shown quite nicely - the other two indexes don't really have much benefit - if you really want to reduce the number of indexes, then drop `SomeIndex1` and `SomeIndex2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all but the last index `SomeIndex3`

The first two indexes are completely redundant.  Also if you do not already have a clustered index on the table and there is no reason to leave it without one, then create a clustered index with the same indexing as `SomeIndex3` and drop `SomeIndex3` as well.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick on that advice about the clustering key without knowing more. A good candidate for a clustering key is narrow, unique, and ever increasing. We don't know anything about the properties of (a,b,c) to say whether any of those apply.